# Dynamically adding a SVG gradient

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have this SVG container with paths. I want to edit it, so the paths' fill will be a pattern. This is my failed attempt:

I add a gradient:

```
$('svg defs').prepend('<linearGradient id="MyGradient"><stop offset="5%" stop-color="#F60" /><stop offset="95%" stop-color="#FF6" /></linearGradient>');
```

And then change the paths' fill:

```
$(base + ' svg path').each(function() {
    this.setAttribute('fill','url(#MyGradient)')
}
```

This doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your problem (what you are "missing") is that jQuery creates new elements in the XHTML namespace, while SVG elements must be created in the SVG namespace. You cannot use raw code in a string for SVG elements.

The simplest (no-plugins) method is to stop leaning on jQuery so much and just use simple DOM methods to create the elements. Yes, it's more verbose than just using jQuery to magically construct your elements for you...but jQuery does not work in this case.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nra29/2/

```
createGradient($('svg')[0],'MyGradient',[
  {offset:'5%', 'stop-color':'#f60'},
  {offset:'95%','stop-color':'#ff6'}
]);
$('svg path').attr('fill','url(#MyGradient)');

// svg:   the owning <svg> element
// id:    an id="..." attribute for the gradient
// stops: an array of objects with <stop> attributes
function createGradient(svg,id,stops){
  var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
  var grad  = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'linearGradient');
  grad.setAttribute('id',id);
  for (var i=0;i<stops.length;i++){
    var attrs = stops[i];
    var stop = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'stop');
    for (var attr in attrs){
      if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr)) stop.setAttribute(attr,attrs[attr]);
    }
    grad.appendChild(stop);
  }

  var defs = svg.querySelector('defs') ||
      svg.insertBefore( document.createElementNS(svgNS,'defs'), svg.firstChild);
  return defs.appendChild(grad);
}
```

#### Using a Library

Alternatively, you can include [Keith Woods' "jQuery SVG" plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) that has a lot of convenience methods for common SVG operations, including the ability to [create linear gradients](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#lineargradient).

Comment: +1: I agree that we should rely less on jQuery, but how verbose is the code WRT the OP snippet. But thanks you for teaching about jsFiddle with useful code.

Comment: @chac How effective is terse code if it does not work? :) This is similar to what Keith Woods' jQuery SVG plugin does, and by placing the DOM code in a re-usable function the code to actually create the gradient is *less* than the jQuery raw XML.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was not aware that elements had namepsaces. I eventually found a more jQuery-friendly way of doing this. I posted it on my answer

Comment: Is there a method that does not use JavaScript? Some websites don't allow JavaScript inside SVG images.

Comment: Really useful to create dynamic gradients.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll have to use the SVG plugin for jQuery (found [here](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)). When adding SVG elements using the "normal" jQuery library, probably the namespaces get mixed up.

Try the following:

```
svg.linearGradient( $('svg defs'), 
                    'MyGradient', 
                    [ ['5%', '#F60'], ['95%', '#FF6']] );
```

(Not exactly sure, however. You might need to fiddle around a bit with that code.)

***EDIT***

Just created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufurA/1/) in order to test the thesis (as suggested by @Phrogz). Indeed it returns `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` as the namespace for the inserted `<linearGradient>`, which is the wrong namespace and thus validates my above speculation.

Comment: @chac That's easy to do; just `console.log($('#MyGradient')[0].namespaceURI)`; if it's not `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` then this is the problem. Sirko should do this rather than just speculate.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution.
It's a bit ugly, but doesn't require the use of additional plugins.

Apparently, a pattern has to be included in the  tag when the SVG is first created (it's probably only read then).

Thus, replacing the SVG tag's wrapper's contents with themselves works (`base` being that wrapper):

```
$(base).html($(base).html())
```

Comment: do I understand correctly that you use just jQuery and in your script assign (to say) `base = $('#embed_container_id')` ? I'm fighting with jQuery.SVG and still miss where the common vs specifics parts of DOM are....

Comment: The reason that works is because placing the element inside the `<svg xmlns="…">` causes it to be created with the correct namespace.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to drop by and say I have found a more elegant solution that allows you to keep using jQuery with SVG elements but without the jQuery SVG library (which is no longer being updated and has some problems with jQuery 1.8 or higher).
Simply use a function like this:

```
createSVGElement= function(element) {
    return $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', element));
}
```

it creates a SVG element on the SVG namespace and encapsulates it with jQuery, once the element is created in the right namespace you can use it freely with jQuery:

You can then use the function in this manner:

```
var $myGradient= createSVGElement('linearGradient')
    .attr( {
        id:"MyGradient"
    });

//if you dont need `defs`, skip this next line
var $myDefs = createSVGElement('defs');

createSVGElement('stop')
    .attr({
        offset: "5%",
        "stop-color": "#F60"
    })
    .appendTo($myGradient);


createSVGElement('stop')
    .attr({
        offset:"95%",
        "stop-color":"#FF6"
    })
    .appendTo($myGradient);

//Use this if you already have `defs`
$('svg defs').prepend($myGradient);

//Use this if you dont have `defs`
$('svg').prepend($myDefs);
$('svg defs').prepend($myGradient);
```

It's not as compact as you might want it to be since you have to create each element by hand, but its a lot better than manipulating everything with DOM methods.

A small note, jQuery .attr() function assumes all attributes are lowercased, which is not the case for SVG elements (for example the `viewBox` attribute in `<svg>` tags). To get around that, when setting attributes with uppercased letters use something like this:

```
$("svg")[0].setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 1000 1000");
```

Comment: Tried this many times and cannot seem to get it to work. Can you provide us with a fiddle so that we can see it in action?

Comment: Hey @fizzix, I see you edited my answer, it had some errors. You got it working? Anyway I just want to add that the attributes in SVG elements are case sensitive. jQuery .attr() function assumes they are not. I will edit the answer and add this information.

Comment: Hey @Hoffmann :) - Unfortunately, I could not get it working in the end and I went for Phrogz solution.