# Can I add a gradient to my SVG using javascript, loading it using an object tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, gradient

I'm downloading a bunch of SVGs using the Noun Project API directly into my code, and I'm wondering if I'd be able to add a linear gradient to these SVGs using some combination of CSS/HTML/vanilla JS. I know that usually, you need to add the linear gradient tag within the SVG, but I want to do this all without manually editing any of the SVG documents I scrape from the API. (The downloaded SVGs don't have any kind of linear gradient tag of course.) How can I make the SVGs be in a gradient?

I've tried the fill: linear gradient with CSS, but that didn't work.

Hoping for some insight into this problem! Anything helps :)

Comment: this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894377/dynamically-adding-a-svg-gradient

Comment: Please read [Change Color of SVG on Hover](https://css-tricks.com/change-color-of-svg-on-hover/)

Comment: @enxaneta thanks! but I asked about gradients, and that article does not cover gradients at all.

Comment: Please look at `Use a mask instead of a background image`. they are using a `background: black;` or `background: red;`. Here you can change it with the gradient